# sql oracle query - order by computed SUM column

Tags: sql, oracle

Friends

In Oracle, is there a way which I can orderby sum in desc?

So basically in below output I want a pages which has got the maximum salary count... i.e. first result should display all details from 58000, 27500, 13000

```
BREAK on DEPARTMENT_ID page  nodup
         on JOB_ID skip 1 nodup
COMPUTE SUM OF SALARY ON DEPARTMENT_ID
```

/

```
DEPARTMENT_ID JOB_ID     LAST_NAME                     SALARY
------------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------
           20 MK_MAN     Hartstein                      13000
************* **********                           ----------
sum                                                     13000

DEPARTMENT_ID JOB_ID     LAST_NAME                     SALARY
------------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------
           80 SA_MAN     Russell                        14000
                         Partners                       13500

************* **********                           ----------
sum                                                     27500

DEPARTMENT_ID JOB_ID     LAST_NAME                     SALARY
------------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------
           90 AD_PRES    King                           24000

              AD_VP      Kochhar                        17000
                         De Haan                        17000

************* **********                           ----------
sum                                                     58000
```

Hope I explained it well..
thank you..

Comment: Oracleuser...no that will give error - not a single-group group function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make it analytical, by finding the `SUM()` of salary in a department before hand, and append it to your regular columns.. Sort it in descending order, and we are done.

You will be able to do with your `sql*plus` reporting still.

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID,
       JOB_ID,
       LAST_NAME,
       SALARY,
       SUM(SALARY) OVER (PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT_ID ORDER BY NULL) as CUMULATIVE_SUM
FROM EMPLOYEE
ORDER BY CUMULATIVE_SUM DESC,DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

To remove from SELECT,

```
ORDER BY SUM(SALARY) OVER (PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT_ID ORDER BY NULL) DESC,DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Comment: OracleUser that was great idea and I'm testing it, but how do you don't list that cumulative column in the report?

Comment: Teplace the cumulative_sum in order by with the entire Sum() row.. an delete it from select, i hope it woks.

Answer (score 2):

More in line with your prose than your code, but if you give your aggregate an alias, you can order by the alias.

```
select somefield, sum(something) total
from whereever
where whatever
group by somefield
order by total desc
```